# function with if...else loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this function in R? The functions can work on a single input, but when I use a vector I get an error:

```r
input_check3 <- function(x){
    if (is.finite(x)) {
        if (x %% 2 == 0){
            print(TRUE)
        } else {
            print(FALSE)
        }
    } else {
       NA
    }
}

data_for_e2 <- c(1, 2, 4, 5, 3)
input_check3(data_for_e2)

#> [1] FALSE
#>  Warning messages:
#>  1: In if (is.finite(x)) { : The length of the condition is greater than one, so only its first element can be used
#>  2: In if (x%%2 == 0) { : The length of the condition is greater than one, so only its first element can be used
```

Comment: `if` isn't vectorized, it only works on a single value. You could use a `for` loop, or `ifelse()`. What is your goal? Just to print messages or to actually get a result?

Comment: `is.finite(1:2)` will return `c(TRUE, TRUE)`, but an `if` statement is looking for only a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ifelse, which is a vectorized function:

```
input_check3 <- function(x){
  ifelse(is.finite(x),
         x %% 2 == 0, # equiv to ifelse(x %% 2 == 0, TRUE, FALSE), thanks Martin Gal!
         NA)
}
```

Result

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: What a concise code! Thank you and Martin very much!